# ASP.NET: How to display a FormView in a (popup) window when item selected in Gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, popup, detailsview, formview

I want my GridView and a FormView (or DetailsView) to work together. When an item in the GridView is selected, I want to open a popup window and display more details about the selected item.

Since I am a beginner, I'd appreciate specific info such as: handle this event in GridView, do this to get the id of GV item selected, make this call to open a new window, in this window make this call to get info associated with the id and display it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might help you: [Master-Detail with the GridView, DetailsView and ModalPopup Controls](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/04/masterdetail_with_the_gridview.html)

Comment: The link appears to be stale. Here is a link, which I believe points to a copy of the article: http://zdima.net/blog/archives/286